# Jest mock if an es6 class returns `{default: f}` instead of `f`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I've been trying to mock an es6 class with jest so that:

1. one can create an instance of the mocked class
2. one can spy on the constructor

pretty much the same as [in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks)

When I do it, I can only succeed with one point - either I make a class without `jest.fn()` I cannot spy on or I get a mock constructor which cannot be "newed" (this option is described here).

#### setup

- it is a 'create-react-app' with typescript app converted to 'react-app-rewired'
- `tsconfig.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
  }
  ```
- some parts of `package.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.27.2",
      "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
      "typescript": "^4.7.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.3.0",
      "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
      "@types/node": "^18.6.3",
      "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
      "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.32.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.32.0",
      "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
      "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
      "eslint": "^8.21.0",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
      "prettier": "^2.7.1",
      "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
      "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
    }
  }
  ```
- there is no special configuration of jest or babel, they are fully managed by the 'create-react-app-rewired' framework (if I understand this correctly)

#### code

##### `test.ts`

```
import Service from '../../../client/service';

jest.mock('../../../client/service', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { getUserById: jest.fn() };
  });
});

test(
    'name',
    async () => {
      await render(
        <ServiceDialog userId={USER_ID} onDone={jest.fn()} />
      );

      await waitFor(() => expect(Service).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
    }
  );
...
```

##### `service.ts`

there is `export default class Service`

##### `ServiceDialog.tsx`

```
...
service.current = new Service();
...
```

#### result

- the test 'name' is successful
- but inside the `ServiceDialog.tsx` on the showed line the making of an instance doesn't work; the `Service` is mocked but looks like this:

  ```
  {default: ƒ}
  > default: f
  > [[Prototype]]: Object
  ```

  the actual class in nested in `default`:

  ```bash
  {default: ƒ}
    default: ƒ () {\n        return fn.apply(this, arguments);\n      }
    _isMockFunction: true
    arguments: ƒ ()
    caller: ƒ ()
    getMockImplementation: () => this._ensureMockConfig(f).mockImpl
    getMockName: () => {\n        const mockConfig = this._ensureMockConfig(f);\n\n        return mockConfig.mockName || 'jest.fn()';\n      }
    mock: () => this._ensureMockState(f)
    mockClear: () => {\n        this._mockState.delete(f);\n\n        return f;\n      }
    mockImplementation: fn => {\n        // next function call will use mock implementation return value\n        const mockConfig = this._ensureMockConfig(f);\n\n        mockConfig.mockImpl = fn;\n        return f;\n      }
    mockImplementationOnce: fn => {\n        // next function call will use this mock implementation return value\n        // or default mock implementation return value\n        const mockConfig = this._ensureMockConfig(f);\n\n        mockConfig.specificMockImpls.push(fn);\n        return f;\n      }
    ...
  ```

  - instead of an instance, one gets `mockConstructor`

#### debugging

- I've already tried everything I found and understood to the topic including adding `__esModule: true` which doesn't help at all
- I believe the problem is in module resolution but can't find a way to solve it
- when I copy the jest docs example into our project, it is only partially working, but unlike our code it produces a newable spyable class - as long as the copied modules are imported per `require()` instead of `import`
- to use `require()` in our code doesn't help, although I would probably have to change every import on the way to `require()`, which I don't want to do

**any help much appreciated**

Comment: Probably it's because of the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` config in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @Teneff Unfortunatelly there is no change when `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false`